# HTML conversion to ASP.NET in Visual Studio

Tags: html

I have a project that is done in HTML but now need to take it in Visual Basic cause it will be coded in ASP.Net.

Any idea what will be changed as far as HTML Markup is concerned to ASP.Net Markup. I know the syntax is different for buttons and Tables.

What will be the quickest way to transition the project to Visual Studio.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Read a manual and then rewrite the code. 2. Hire a dev. 3. Search online for `HTML to ASP.NET converter`

Comment: http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/response.right/default.php

Answer (score 0):

You ASP.NET MVC, so 99% markup will apply. ASP.NET MVC is an ASP.NET application, so it should apply. Simple tutorial is [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0):

To open your website in VS, simply go to File -> Open -> Web Site and locate your website folder.

From there, the changes are up to you. Website should run without any additional changes if it's pure HTML, but any VB additions will have to be done from scratch. You can use existing controls on website and just convert them to server ones [runat="server"] (in simple cases) and copy them to newly created web-form pages.

The question is quite general.. in current state, the best answer would probably be "learn at least the basics of ASP.NET here: [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)"